# Perimeter of Inscribed Square - Paradox?

Tags: geometry, circles, paradoxes

1. Imagine a simple X / Y coordinate graph. A circle surrounds the point of origin. Let's say the radius = 3.
2. We want to know how many points exist on the circumference of the circle through which a line may be drawn from the point and cross the origin.
3. Here, we simply find the circumference of the circle, which is 18.85
4. Simple enough. But now, what if we draw a square within this circle? The perimeter of this inscribed square would be 16.97, which is smaller than the circumference of the outside circle.

But: if the perimeter of this inscribed square is smaller and therefore fewer points exist through which a line may be drawn through + point of origin, how do we reconcile this with the fact that *every point which may be drawn on the outlying circle's larger circumference MUST ALSO cross through the square's perimeter*?

For every point on the circumference of the circle through which a line may be drawn through the point of origin, a point must exist on that line which also lies on the perimeter the inner square. Therefore, the same amount of points must exist on the perimeter of the square.

Comment: A circle has infinitely many points on its circumference. You can't count them.

Comment: so does the permitter of a square (or any shape), though. And yet some perimeters are larger than others and are calculably so.

Comment: The error is the step from "square has smaller perimeter than circle" to "square has fewer points than circle." The length of a curve is not a measure of how many points it contains.

Comment: Suppose that we place points at circle with some numerical density $d$, then number of points on circle is $\frac{2\pi r}{d}$. The same number of points for square gives different average numerical density $\langle d\rangle_{square}=\frac{4 a d}{2\pi r}$

Comment: Welcome to infinity! You could make a similar reasoning with positive integers, which "are more" than even integers. See here: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InfiniteSet.html

Comment: ah! Thank you intelligenti pauca. I thought I had stumbled upon something like that, just wasn't sure if it meant anything or if anyone had made an argument like that before as it relates to shapes. Thanks!